# Count chars and words in text, can it be optimized?

Tags: c#

I want to count chars in a big text, I do it with this code:

```
string s = textBox.Text;
int chars = 0;
int words = 0;

foreach(var v in s.ToCharArray())
    chars++;

foreach(var v in s.Split(' '))
    words++;
```

this code works but it seems pretty slow with large text, so how can i improve this?

Comment: Edited, sry i messed up

Comment: This would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You definitely want to count spaces in the char count then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need another char-array, you can use `String.Length` directly:

```
int chars = s.Length;
int words = s.Split().Length;
```

Side-note: if you call `String.Split` without an argument all [white-space characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) are used as delimiter. Those include spaces, tab-characters and new-line characters. This is not a complete list of possible word delimiters but it's better than `" "`.

You are also counting consecutive spaces as different "words". Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] wordSeparators = { "\r\n", "\n", ",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":", " ", "-", "/", "\\", "[", "]", "(", ")", "<", ">", "@", "\"", "'" }; // this list is probably too extensive, tim.schmelter@myemail.com would count as 4 words, but it should give you an idea
string[] words = s.Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int wordCount = words.Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single pass through without making a copy of your string:

```
int chars = 0;
int words = 0;

//keep track of spaces so as to only count nonspace-space-nonspace transitions
//it is initialized to true to count the first word only when we come to it
bool lastCharWasSpace = true;

foreach (var c in s)
{
    chars++;

    if (c == ' ')
    {
        lastCharWasSpace = true;
    }
    else if (lastCharWasSpace)
    {
        words++;
        lastCharWasSpace = false;
    }       
}
```

Note the reason I do not use `string.Split` here is that it *does a bunch of string copies under the hood* to return the resulting array. Since you're not using the contents but instead are only interested in the count, this is a waste of time and memory - especially if you have a big enough text that has to be shuffled off to main memory, or worse yet swap space.

Do be aware that `string.Split` *does* on the other hand by default use a longer list of delimiters than just `' '`, so you may want to add other conditions to the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
int numberOfLetters = textBox.Length;
```

or use LINQ

```
int numberOfLetters = textBox.ToCharArray().Count();
```

or

```
int numberOfLetters = 0;
foreach (char letter in textBox)
{
    numberOfLetters++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chars = textBox.Text.Length;
var words = textbox.Text.Count(c => c == ' ') + 1;
```